# Error: pytesseract module is not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract

When I am trying to install pytesseract in anaconda prompt. It says "`package already installed`". But when I run command "`import pytesseract` " error show "`module is not found`"

Answer (score 0):

**Did you install PIL/pillow** alongside pytesseract? According to [this webpage](https://grimhacker.com/2014/11/23/installing-pytesseract-practically-painless/), PIL is required for pytesseract to work.

To install PIL (assuming you configured python normally when you installed it), open up command prompt as administrator and type: "**python -m pip install pillow**" (without quotes)

If you already have PIL installed:

**Is the pytesseract module in the same directory/folder as the python.exe interpreter you are using? If not, is it in the same directory/folder as the program you are trying to import it into?**

You should either:

- Drag a copy of pytesseract into the same folder as the python.exe interpreter you are using (your best bet)
- Drag a copy of pytesseract into your program directory (probably your next best option)

  or
- Follow the instructions provided in one of the answers [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder) to import pytesseract from a remote directory (not ideal).

If my answer doesn't work for you, leave a comment and I can try and help further.

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for your support. But i have already installed pillow. but idle is showing  same error.

Comment: File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 60, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

**this error comes after importing pytesseract**

Comment: It looks like you are trying to import the PIL (and probably pytesseract) module from the directory "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\".

What version of Python are you using?

This directory will change slightly depending on your username and current Python version, but your modules are more likely located in the directory: 

"C:\Users\(your username)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37" ("Python37" might be 36, 35, etc... depending on your python version.

Comment: Thanks, But i resolve the issue by uninstalling the pytesseract and again install with the help of pip